# How to connect your KSQLDB-Cluster on OpenShift to an on-premise kerberized Kafka-cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, openshift, ksqldb

**What I want to achieve:**
We have an on premise Kafka cluster. I want to set up KSQLDB in OpenShift and connect it to the brokers of the on premise Kafka cluster.

**The problem:**
When I try to start the KSQLDB server with the command "/usr/bin/ksql-server-start /etc/ksqldb/ksql-server.properties" I get the error message:

```
[2020-05-14 15:47:48,519] ERROR Failed to start KSQL (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain:60)
io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlServerException: Could not get Kafka cluster configuration!
        at io.confluent.ksql.services.KafkaClusterUtil.getConfig(KafkaClusterUtil.java:90)
        at io.confluent.ksql.security.KsqlAuthorizationValidatorFactory.isKafkaAuthorizerEnabled(KsqlAuthorizationValidatorFactory.java:81)
        at io.confluent.ksql.security.KsqlAuthorizationValidatorFactory.create(KsqlAuthorizationValidatorFactory.java:51)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.buildApplication(KsqlRestApplication.java:624)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.buildApplication(KsqlRestApplication.java:544)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.createExecutable(KsqlServerMain.java:98)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.main(KsqlServerMain.java:56)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1589471268517) timed out at 1589471268518 after 1 attempt(s)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
        at io.confluent.ksql.services.KafkaClusterUtil.getConfig(KafkaClusterUtil.java:60)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1589471268517) timed out at 1589471268518 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

**My configuration:**
I set up my Dockerfile on the basis of this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/ksqldb-server, the ports 9092, 9093, 8080, 8082 and 443 are open.

My service-yaml looks like that:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: social-media-dev
  namespace: abc
  selfLink: xyz
  uid: xyz
  resourceVersion: '1'
  creationTimestamp: '2020-05-14T09:47:15Z'
  labels:
    app: social-media-dev
  annotations:
    openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
spec:
  ports:
    - name: social-media-dev
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
      nodePort: 31364
  selector:
    app: social-media-dev
    deploymentconfig: social-media-dev
  clusterIP: XX.XX.XXX.XXX
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalIPs:
    - XXX.XX.XXX.XXX
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: XX.XX.XXX.XXX
```

My ksql-server.properties file includes the following information:
listeners: http://0.0.0.0:8082
bootstrap.servers: X.X.X.X:9092, X.X.X.Y:9092, X.X.X.Z:9092

**What I have tried so far:**

I tried to connect from within my pod to a broker and it worked: 
`(timeout 1 bash -c '</dev/tcp/X.X.X.X/9092 && echo PORT OPEN || echo PORT CLOSED') 2>/dev/null`
result: PORT OPEN

I also played around with the listener but then the error message got shorter just with the information "Could not get Kafka cluster configuration!" and without the timeout error.

I tried to exchange LoadBalancer to Nodeport, but also without success.

Do you have any ideas what I could try next?

UPDATE: With an upgrade to Cloudera CDH6, the Cloudera Kafka cluster works now also with Kafka Streams. Hence I was able to connect from my KSQLDB Cluster in Openshift to the on-premise Kafka cluster now.

Comment: Using kafkacat from where you're running ksqlDB, can you successfully connect to the brokers and return metadata (using the `-L` flag)?

Comment: Thanks @RobinMoffatt I will try that, but it's a little bit challenging getting librdkafka-devel for kafkacat running on RHEL8.

Comment: If you're running ksqlDB as Docker container, you can run `kafkacat` as Docker container too :)

Comment: Thanks I just got it running. So with kafkacat I can see all our topics, partitions, leaders etc. So this works.

Comment: I guess @RobinMoffatt that it's then probably an issue with the kafka listener? I don't run it on the default port, because it's not open and instead used 8083. 8083 isn't used by another process, I already checked that.

Comment: The error is being reported because ksqlDB is failing to get the Kafka cluster's config when starting up.  Sorry, I don't know openshift, so can't comment on what config needs to change to enable ksql to talk to Kafka.

Comment: Thank you Robin and Andrew. I found out that the version of our Cloudera Kafka cluster is too old and doesn't support Kafka Streams - which is available starting with CDK 4.0.0. As our migration will be next month, I'll give an update on stackoverflow. For the time being I'll prepare everything with Confluent Operator on OpenShift and  hopefully be able to migrate next month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:
With an upgrade to Cloudera CDH6, the Cloudera Kafka cluster works now also with Kafka Streams. Hence I was able to connect from my KSQLDB Cluster in Openshift to the on-premise Kafka cluster now.

I will also describe my final way of connecting to the kerberized Kafka-cluster here as I have been struggling a lot to get it running:

1. Getting Kerberos-tickets and establish connections via SSL

ksql-server.properties (the sasl_ssl part of it):

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI

ssl.truststore.location=truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
ssl.truststore.type=JKS

ssl.ca.location=cert

sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useKeyTab=true storeKey=true keyTab="my.keytab" serviceName="kafka"  principal="myprincipal";
serviceName="kafka"

producer.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
producer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
producer.ssl.truststore.location=truststore.jks
producer.ssl.truststore.password=password
producer.sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
producer.sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useKeyTab=true storeKey=true keyTab="my.keytab" serviceName="kafka"  principal="myprincipal";

consumer.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
consumer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
consumer.ssl.truststore.location=truststore.jks
consumer.ssl.truststore.password=password
consumer.sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
consumer.sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useKeyTab=true storeKey=true keyTab="my.keytab" serviceName="kafka"  principal="myprincipal";`
```

2. Set up Sentry rules therefore

`HOST=[HOST]->CLUSTER=kafka-cluster->action=idempotentwrite`

`HOST=[HOST]->TRANSACTIONALID=[ID]->action=describe`

`HOST=[HOST]->TRANSACTIONALID=[ID]->action=write`