# "Transactional Id authorization failed" when trying to create a stream in Ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a KSQL server set up in OpenShift and connected to the on-premise Cloudera Kafka cluster (CDH6) (kerberized and with SSL). When I do a list topics- or print-command everything works fine. But as soon as I want to create a stream, I get the following error:

```
Could not write the statement 'create stream dev_abc (date varchar, timestamp varchar, latitude varchar, longitude varchar) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='topic123', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');' into the command topic: Transactional Id authorization failed.
Caused by: Transactional Id authorization failed.
```

When having a look into the log file, I see also this error:

```
[2020-11-18 11:53:58,090] INFO Processed unsuccessfully: KsqlRequest{ksql='CREATE STREAM KSQL_PROCESSING_LOG (logger VARCHAR, level VARCHAR, time BIGINT, message STRUCT<type INT, deserializationError STRUCT<target VARCHAR, errorMessage VARCHAR, recordB64 VARCHAR, cause ARRAY<VARCHAR>, `topic` VARCHAR>, recordProcessingError STRUCT<errorMessage VARCHAR, record VARCHAR, cause ARRAY<VARCHAR>>, productionError STRUCT<errorMessage VARCHAR>, serializationError STRUCT<target VARCHAR, errorMessage VARCHAR, record VARCHAR, cause ARRAY<VARCHAR>, `topic` VARCHAR>, kafkaStreamsThreadError STRUCT<errorMessage VARCHAR, threadName VARCHAR, cause ARRAY<VARCHAR>>>) WITH(KAFKA_TOPIC='service_uykh7k6ksql_processing_log', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');', configOverrides={}, requestProperties={}, commandSequenceNumber=Optional[-1]}, reason: Could not write the statement 'CREATE STREAM KSQL_PROCESSING_LOG (logger VARCHAR, level VARCHAR, time BIGINT, message STRUCT<type INT, deserializationError STRUCT<target VARCHAR, errorMessage VARCHAR, recordB64 VARCHAR, cause ARRAY<VARCHAR>, `topic` VARCHAR>, recordProcessingError STRUCT<errorMessage VARCHAR, record VARCHAR, cause ARRAY<VARCHAR>>, productionError STRUCT<errorMessage VARCHAR>, serializationError STRUCT<target VARCHAR, errorMessage VARCHAR, record VARCHAR, cause ARRAY<VARCHAR>, `topic` VARCHAR>, kafkaStreamsThreadError STRUCT<errorMessage VARCHAR, threadName VARCHAR, cause ARRAY<VARCHAR>>>) WITH(KAFKA_TOPIC='service_abc_processing_log', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');' into the command topic: Transactional Id authorization failed. (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.resources.KsqlResource:301)
```

**I am working right now with this configurations:**
image: confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.13.0 (but also tried older ones)

ksql-server.properties:

```
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8088

#to avoid Attempted to write a non-default includeClusterAuthorizedOperations at version 7
ksql.access.validator.enable=off

kafka.confluent.support.metrics.enable=false

security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
ssl.truststore.location=/.../.../truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=XXXXX
ssl.truststore.type=JKS

sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useKeyTab=true storeKey=true keyTab="blablub.keytab" serviceName="kafka"  principal="principalname";

serviceName="kafka"

principal="principalname";

ksql.service.id=myservicename

# authentication for producers, needed for ksql commands like "Create Stream"
producer.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
producer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
producer.ssl.truststore.location=/.../truststore.jks
producer.ssl.truststore.password=XXXXX
producer.sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
producer.sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useKeyTab=true storeKey=true keyTab="....keytab" serviceName="kafka"  principal="principalname";

# authentication for consumers, needed for ksql commands like "Create Stream"
consumer.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
consumer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
consumer.ssl.truststore.location=/..../truststore.jks
consumer.ssl.truststore.password=XXXXX
consumer.sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
consumer.sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useKeyTab=true storeKey=true keyTab="/.....keytab" serviceName="kafka"  principal="principalname";

#------ Logging config -------

# Automatically create the processing log topic if it does not already exist:
ksql.logging.processing.topic.auto.create=false
ksql.logging.processing.topic.name=abc_processing_log
# Automatically create a stream within KSQL for the processing log:
ksql.logging.processing.stream.auto.create=true

#------ External service config -------

# The set of Kafka brokers to bootstrap Kafka cluster information from:

bootstrap.servers=.....:9093,.....:9093,......:9093
```

I found a lot about using Kafka ACLs to avoid such kind of errors, but that's not supported in CDH. Do you have any ideas of how to move on with analyzing?

Comment: you found a solution ?

Comment: Yes I did (months later), in my case the problem were missing Sentry rules, please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61816185/how-to-connect-your-ksqldb-cluster-on-openshift-to-an-on-premise-kerberized-kafk/64893201#64893201

Answer (score 0):

The missing Sentry-rules therefore were:

```
HOST=[HOST]->CLUSTER=kafka-cluster->action=idempotentwrite

HOST=[HOST]->TRANSACTIONALID=[ID]->action=describe

HOST=[HOST]->TRANSACTIONALID=[ID]->action=write
```

as described also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61816185/how-to-connect-your-ksqldb-cluster-on-openshift-to-an-on-premise-kerberized-kafk/64893201#64893201).